# Can asmx be considered an alternative to xml?

Tags: asp.net, xml, web-services, http, asmx

If not what is the difference between the two formats?

I know both are used for exchanging information between clients (apps, browsers, etc.) and web services.

Answer (score 1):

Those are two different kinds of things.  XML is a data format.  ASMX is a .Net program that can use XML.